# jQuery to pure javascript conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I am not using any external libraries, I would like to convert the following fiddle to a non-jQuery version of: [this page](http://jsfiddle.net/nc6NW/1/)

```
$(':text').keyup(function() {
    if($('#first_name').val() != "" && $('#second_name').val() != "") {
       $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
       $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);   
    }
});
```

Comment: `As I am not using any external libraries`, why not?

Comment: Clues: Use vanilla JS, getElementsByTagName, loop, EventListener, .value, .disabled etc...

Comment: I'm designing a very simple HTA application that can be ran via intranet and not internet. Trying to keep it simple.

Comment: jQuery does keep it simple, IMO.

Comment: I'm with Jason on this one. Just include jQuery locally.

Comment: Specially if you don't know how to write simple native Javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/nc6NW/180/

```
var first = document.getElementById('first_name'),
    second = document.getElementById('second_name'),
    submit = document.getElementById('submit');
first.onkeyup = second.onkeyup = function() {
    submit.disabled = !(first.value && second.value);
};
```

Comment: Thanks so very much! Appreciate it a huge bunch =)